# Bootstrap 4 input group RTL issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a requirement to make a bootstrap v4 page RTL.

As I add the `dir="rtl"` attribute, the `input-group` element styles are messed up:

```html
<link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" dir="rtl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
      <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <span class="input-group-addon">0.00</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using *Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6*

I'm looking for a way to fix those styles?

Answer (score 3):

As RTL support will come later - [from github commet](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/17279#issuecomment-181151047):

> There isn't one, but don't worry, given the number of times folks have asked for RTL, we won't soon forget about it. But we're not going to delay v4.0.0 for this. RTL will probably land in a later minor release (e.g. v4.2.0)

I've created a CSS snippet which fixes the RTL issue for the `input group` elements:

```
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-addon:not(:last-child){
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-left: 0;
}

[dir="rtl"] .input-group .form-control:not(:last-child),
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-addon:not(:last-child),
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:first-child)>.btn-group:not(:last-child)>.btn,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:first-child)>.btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle),
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:last-child)>.btn,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:last-child)>.btn-group>.btn,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:last-child)>.dropdown-toggle{
  border-bottom-right-radius: .25rem;
  border-top-right-radius: .25rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

[dir="rtl"] .input-group .form-control:not(:first-child),
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-addon:not(:first-child),
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:first-child)>.btn,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:first-child)>.btn-group>.btn,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:first-child)>.dropdown-toggle,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:last-child)>.btn-group:not(:first-child)>.btn,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:last-child)>.btn:not(:first-child){
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .25rem;
  border-top-left-radius: .25rem;
}

[dir="rtl"] .form-control + .input-group-addon:not(:first-child){
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-right: 0;
}

[dir="rtl"] .input-group .form-control:not(:first-child):not(:last-child),
[dir="rtl"] .input-group .input-group-addon:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

Check the snippet:

```css
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-addon:not(:last-child){
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-left: 0;
}

[dir="rtl"] .input-group .form-control:not(:last-child),
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-addon:not(:last-child),
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:first-child)>.btn-group:not(:last-child)>.btn,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:first-child)>.btn:not(:last-child):not(.dropdown-toggle),
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:last-child)>.btn,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:last-child)>.btn-group>.btn,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:last-child)>.dropdown-toggle{
  border-bottom-right-radius: .25rem;
  border-top-right-radius: .25rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
}

[dir="rtl"] .input-group .form-control:not(:first-child),
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-addon:not(:first-child),
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:first-child)>.btn,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:first-child)>.btn-group>.btn,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:first-child)>.dropdown-toggle,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:last-child)>.btn-group:not(:first-child)>.btn,
[dir="rtl"] .input-group-btn:not(:last-child)>.btn:not(:first-child){
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: .25rem;
  border-top-left-radius: .25rem;
}

[dir="rtl"] .form-control + .input-group-addon:not(:first-child){
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-right: 0;
}

[dir="rtl"] .input-group .form-control:not(:first-child):not(:last-child),
[dir="rtl"] .input-group .input-group-addon:not(:first-child):not(:last-child){
  border-radius: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" dir="rtl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <label for="basic-url">Your vanity URL</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
      <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
      <span class="input-group-addon">0.00</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The values I used (`1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15)` and `.25rem`) are default in current version of bootstrap v4.